# How many parentheses can I skip in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

I am new to Groovy and while reading the book *Groovy in Action*, I learned that I can skip the parentheses that we use in Java to enclose the arguments. Fine. To test that out I wrote a simple Groovy script (*program* isn't the right word, is it ?)

Here it is:

```
import java.text.*
DateFormat fmt = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance()
println fmt.format(new Date())
```

This runs perfect. However, when I remove the parentheses around the `new Date()`, I get an error that:

```
Exception thrown

groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: format for class: java.text.SimpleDateFormat 
    at ConsoleScript8.run(ConsoleScript8:3)
```

**What is going wrong?** Why can't I skip those parentheses ?

Comment: You're trying to use Date as an argument of `format` method. But it should be `String` http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#format%28java.lang.String%29 . Something like `today = new Date();`
`today = today.format("yyyy-MM-dd");`

Comment: @olyv http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because Groovy parses code missing parenthesis considering the first call as a method on `this` object. So when you write:

```
println fmt.format new Date()
```

Groovy parses into:

```
println(fmt.format).new Date()
```

This will give an error stating you are missing a `format` property for the class `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

Take this example:

```
e = new Expando()
e.format = {
  "format called"
}

def foo = {
  println it
  it()
}

foo e.format new Date()
```

The result will be:

```
MissingPropertyException: No such property: Wed Nov 20 10:05:32 2013 for class: java.lang.String
```

Groovy understands it as:

```
print( e.format ).new Date()
```

So it is trying to get the property `new Date()` from the result of the `print()` function.

---

For a simple date formatting, you can just use the `Date.format` method:

```
println new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

As for Groovy rules, take [this example](http://glaforge.appspot.com/article/nicer-dsls-in-groovy-1-8-thanks-to-extended-command-expressions) into account:

```
drink tea with sugar and milk
```

What Groovy understand is:

```
drink(tea).with(sugar).and(milk)
```

Very good for DSLs ;-).